# SQL Server - Replace Char(32) Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with EmailAddress column contains spaces. I performed a mass update to remove all the spaces and it worked for most of records. I randomly check and one of the email addresses has a space (Char 32) at the end, but didn't get removed.  I tried a lot of things, but did not work.

Here is my mass Update Query:

```
Update ContactTable
SET EmailAddress = REPLACE(EmailAddress, ' ', '')
```

For the email address that has a space at the end,  I copied and pasted it in this query below to list all out the chars with Ascii numbers to see if it is really Char 32 and it is.

```
DECLARE @YourString   varchar(500)

SELECT @YourString='dept.com '

;WITH AllNumbers AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM AllNumbers
        WHERE Number<DATALENGTH(@YourString)
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@YourString,Number,1) AS CharText,ASCII(SUBSTRING(@YourString,Number,1)) AscNum, Number
, case when SUBSTRING(@YourString,Number,1) like '[ ]%'
    THEN 'y'
    ELSE 'n'
 END SpaceFound
FROM AllNumbers

-------------------------------------------------
Output Result (# 9 is the Char 32):
CharText    AscNum  Number  SpaceFound
d           100     1       n
e           101     2       n
p           112     3       n
t           116     4       n
.           46      5       n
c           99      6       n
o           111     7       n
m           109     8       n
            32      9       y
```

I tried this update query and it didn't work either:

```
Update ContactTable
SET EmailAddress = REPLACE(EmailAddress, char(32), '')
```

Of course, I can manually delete the trailing space for this particular record, but there may be more like this one.

Updated: I even tried to use this function below to replace, but didn't work either:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TRIM](@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN

    --Horizontal Tab
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(9),'');
    --Line Feed
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(10),'');
    --Vertical Tab
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(11),'');
    --Form Feed
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(12),'');
    --Carriage Return
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(13),'');
    --Column Break
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(14),'');
    --Non-breaking space
    Set @string = Replace(@string,CHAR(160),'');

    Set @string = LTRIM(RTRIM(@string));
    Return @string
END

Update ContactTable
SET EmailAddress = dbo.Trim(EmailAddress)
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like it really isn't a space after all.  It could be a tab or something else.

Comment: Does the same happen using RTRIM()? In most environments trailing spaces are ignored so is this really a problem anyway? i.e. are you going to continue to clean up the tables as errors are entered? just wondering.

Comment: try char(10) and char(13)

Comment: try to cast that character as binary.  A space should yield a result of "0x20000..."   select cast(' ' as binary)

Comment: I tried RTRIM, and LTRIM already, but it didn't work.

Comment: Char(9) should work for tabs. Can you give sample data?

Comment: is it really a space or something else? try `SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(YourColumn,1)) FROM YourTable WHERE YourPK=x`

Comment: There is something you aren't telling us. I can reproduce the results accurately.  http://rextester.com/MREHK87103

Comment: Can you add a script that reproduces the problem?   I agree with scsimon above.

Comment: I ran a couple more times with the dbo.Trim() function and it took it.  I don't why I didn't work at the first time.  I apologize for all the confusion guys!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use the length (LEN) function to determine if there are any changes before and after you have manually removed the extra space. If there are changes in the length then you can try and use it to determine email addresses with extract spaces.

Answer (score -1):

The function `len` use the amount character of string while `datalenght` do use the amount of bit

Comment: If I use LEN, it will not list the space character.  I wanted to see what char# at the end.

Answer (score -1):

`CHAR(32)` is a funny character. If it appears at the end of a string, SQL Server will simply ignore it.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABC' = 'ABC' + CHAR(32) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END;
```

will return `TRUE`, but only because the character is at the end of the string.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABC' = CHAR(32) + 'ABC' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END;
```

will (as expected) return `FALSE`.

Counting lengths are also affected. `LEN(CHAR(32))` returns `0`, but `DATALENGTH(CHAR(32))` returns `1`.